# Full width section titles in tufte-latex

Tags: sectioning, tufte, fullwidth

I am using tufte-latex and would like my section titles to use the full width of the page in the case that I use a fullwidth environment for the next block of text. However, when I try to compile this example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
\section{This is the Title of my Section, Which I Will Make Very Long to Demonstrate the Problem I Have Using Fullwidth}
\lipsum
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

**LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item**

However, if I run the code like this, it works, but gives me a too-narrow section header.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}

\section{This is the Title of my Section, Which I Will Make Very Long to Demonstrate the Problem I Have Using Fullwidth}
\begin{fullwidth}
\lipsum
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: too-narrow section header]

Comment: Out of interest, are you always using the whole width?

Comment: No. For the most part my document has a lot of margin figures and margin notes. There are a couple sections that start with a page or two of all text, so I make those fullwidth.

Comment: FOr the sake of consistency, i would stick to the rather narrow column and not extend the text into the margin.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I will leave it to you to convince the person whose book I am typesetting to agree to that. I have already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea for readability and consistency, but if you really must stretch the section heading across the full page, the following should work:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\titleformat{\section}%
  [display]% shape
  {\relax\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\begin{fullwidth}}{}\normalfont\Large\itshape}% format applied to label+text
  {\thesection}% label
  {1em}% horizontal separation between label and title body
  {}% before the title body
  [\ifthenelse{\NOT\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}{\end{fullwidth}}{}]% after the title body

\usepackage{lipsum}% provides filler text

\begin{document}

\section{This is a lengthy section heading to demonstrate it sprawls across the entire page width}

\begin{fullwidth}
\lipsum
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

Note also that the `fullwidth` environment is not designed two work across page boundaries and it may break in some cases. (The block of text will be offset horizontally on the page.)

Comment: is the syntax correct here? not working for me.