# fullwidth environment in tufte latex

Tags: fullwidth

I used two column in `fullwidth` environment in tufte latex but occur error at even page.

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum{1}
\lipsum{1}
\lipsum{2}
\end{multicols}
\end{fullwidth}
```

*following MWE pasted from the comments*

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{fullwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum{1} \lipsum{1} \lipsum{2}
  \end{multicols}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```

The trouble seems to be that the block of text is shifted to  the left (or right) so much that it moves partly out of the page.

please help me!
Thank you very much!
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide the full mwe including the `\documentclass` upto `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi AJN, the error is letters at the odd page askew to the left. \documentclass[twoside,symmetric,justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum{1}

\lipsum{1}

\lipsum{2}
\end{multicols}

\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}

Comment: The problem seems to be due to the use of the option `symmetric` along with the `full width` environment as far as i can tell. The CTAN sample book does not seem to mention if full width environment and symmetric option are incompatible.

Comment: As an exercise, I removed the `multicols` environment from your MWE and broke up the `fullwidth` environment into several copies with each containing 3 paragraphs of `lipsum`. I noticed that when the aux file is not up to date with the contents, the same problem appears. However, upon compiling again, the `aux` file becomes consistent and the text is typeset properly. Can you elaborate a little more on why you need large chunks of text in the `fullwidth` environment? Can you break it up into smaller pieces? Can you shed some light on the actual document you are typesetting?

Comment: If you are not using the `marginpar` or other margin notes and if you don't want to leave space in the margins for the book reader, consider removing the symmetric option or use some package like `geometry` to reduce margin size rather than using `fullwidth` environment.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294554 @goodbyk says  `Note also that the fullwidth environment is not designed two work across page boundaries and it may break in some cases. (The block of text will be offset horizontally on the page.)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It's ok when I remove option symmetric! How to use both option symmetric and fullwidth environment?

Comment: My understanding is that the `full-width` environment is useful only for *short* paragraphs of text where you want to use the margin note space also for the text. If you want very long sections of full width text, you effectively don't have margin note space in those pages and hence the symmetric option does not make sense. It may be better to use packages like geometry to remove the margin not space rather than use the full width environment.