# Full-width sections appearing off margin in tufte-style book

Tags: latex3, fullwidth, tufte-book

I am using `\documentclass[justified, twoside, symmetric]{tufte-book}`.

But my `\begin{fullwidth}` text is moving off-margins particular pages (please see the image below).  I have tried adjusting the margins, which sort of works, but then the rest of the text is shifted over there, too (such as the headers).  Does anyone know how I can fix this, please?

Many many thanks :)

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[justified, twoside, symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\pagebreak

\begin{fullwidth}
    \lipsum[1-20]
\end{fullwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here's what's happening]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: Thanks, José, I've edited the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tex.stackexchange.com/a/294554](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294420/full-width-section-titles-in-tufte-latex/294554#294554) @goodbyk says Note also that the fullwidth environment is not designed two work across page boundaries and it may break in some cases. (The block of text will be offset horizontally on the page.)

So...

I instead of using the \fullwidth, I used `\newgeometry{bottom=25mm, vmargin=3cm, hmargin=3.5cm}`.  Which did the trick, but now the headers don't conform to the new geometry.  So, I used the `fancyhdr` package to sort that out.  So now...

```
\documentclass[justified, twoside, symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \pagebreak
    
    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
    \fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}
    
    \lipsum[1-20]
    \restoregeometry
    
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Generates the desired formatting, like in the picture below.  Hope this helps someone

[image: Example of how this looks across pages]